# Do all federation ships have holodecks?

Tags: star-trek

Do all Federation ships have a holodeck? I can't really see the smaller ships having them, but it does seem like a standard thing on federation ships.

Also whilst we're discussing it do Vulcan ships have holodecks or are they not allowed, and what other species have holodeck technology are is it just a federation thing?

Comment: I think the Defiant might qualify as a smaller ship, but it's still a prominent Federation vessel.  And, I don't think it had a holodeck.  Also, your question should be split into about two or three:  1.)  Do all federation ships have holodecks?  (And, you may want to specify time period, since they did not exist pre-TNG.)  2.)  Are Vulcans allowed to have holodecks?  3.)  Do non-Federation races have holodeck technology?

Comment: My brain is too fried right now to answer this.. but if anyone wants to [this Memory Alpha link](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Holodeck) has most of the answers.

Comment: I recall in TNG that in the earlier episodes they marveled at the "new" holodeck, something that most of the crew members were not used to, so I would speculate that at that time probably not. However later on in the series it seemed to be more of a normal thing, I believe in Hollow Pursuits it was mentioned that psychological studies were being done on holodeck addiction(though they didn't specify ships).

Comment: Shuttles certainly don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they do not. The [USS Equinox](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Equinox) doesn't, as seen in the episode [Equinox, Part 2](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Equinox,_Part_II_%28episode%29). They only have a [synaptic stimulator](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Synaptic_stimulator), which the crew describes as "a poor man's holodeck".

From the [Memory Alpha page about the decks of the Nova class](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nova_class_decks), we also directly see that there is no holo deck (nor holo room, besides the sick bay). Note that holo decks are listed on Memory Alpha, if they exist (see [Intrepid class decks](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Intrepid_class#Decks)).

Comment: While I could not find evidence to the contrary, It would be worthy to point out, that the USS Equinox was highly damaged by the time Voyager encountered it and they did have a holo doctor, so the technology was on the ship. Whether they had an actual working holo-deck is unknown, maybe someone with ship schematics could give a definitive canon answer here.

Comment: @Jared: Thanks for that. I added more details that strongly support the lack of holo decks.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but did the captain of the Equinox not say they did not have the power to run the holodeck or they had been to badly damaged they did not work anymore?

Comment: @mattInman: I don't recall that right now. If I rewatch the episode someday soon, I'll get back to this.

Answer (score 3):

As noted, at the beginning of TNG the holodecks were a new accessory for Starfleet vessels.  The Galaxy Class being among the largest vessels at the time of TNG had 16 holodecks.  I would assume that holodecks were installed depending on the tour lengths the vessel was expected to perform and the size of the crew.  The Enterprise D and Voyager both were going to have extended tours, being away from spacedock for extended periods, from months to whole years, and would need to have sufficient recreational outlets on board.

Where as the Defiant and Equinox, which did not have holodecks, were both short tour vessels. The Defiant rarely going on missions longer than a month or two and being based out of a starbase, or attached to a fleet that would provide extended support.  And the Equinox which was designed for short term, planetary research, probably to be based out of a starbase or attached to a fleet where they would provide a non-combat support role.

Another factor in determining whether a ship would have a holodeck on board would be power availability.  Holodecks are very power intensive systems, as seen in episodes where the holodeck won't disengage and the power drain puts the ship in jeopardy.  Only vessels with powerful generative capabilities would be able to afford the power required to run one regularly.

Comment: I thought the holodeck had an independant power source that was incompatible with the rest of the ship.

Comment: I don't think so... There are quite a few Voyager episodes where they make the point of shutting down the holodecks because they are drawing too much power.  Also I think there are one or two TNG episodes where because they can't shut down a holodeck drawing to much power the ship was in danger.